# Не отображаются стили css в html страничке

Tags: java, html, css, spring, thymeleaf

Не подтягивается стиль css в html файл, путь вроде указал правильный, прикреплю ниже
Пробовал класть в один каталог с html - не работает, с путями тоже пробовал играться

[image: Пример структуры папок]

В браузере в консоли такая вот ошибка
This page failed to load a stylesheet from a URL.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Попробуйте такой путь: ../../css/style.css

Comment: @Dovgai Dima к сожалению так тоже не работает, страница отображается так же без стилей и с такой вот ошибкой в консоли в браузере
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8081/login' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: Похоже, следует указать MIME-тип ресурса в теге `link`: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/style.css">`